# List slicing and making a copy

Tags: python, list

While reading about slicing a list; i got stuck here:-

```
a = [1, 3, 5]
b = a[:]
a[:] = [x**2 for x in a]
a[:] = [0]
print(b) # output --> [1,3,5]
```

And this:-

```
a = [1, 3, 5]
b = a
a[:] = [x**2 for x in a]
a[:] = [0]
print(b) # output --> [0]
```

I know that `b = a[:]` is making a copy of list `a`  but then what `b=a` is doing in the second example? And when printing the outputs, in the first case `b` doesn't get modified but get modified in second one. What is the reason for this behavior?
I am not asking about how to do slicing, but wondering why both the codes mentioned are behaving strangely and differently.

Comment: In the second case you set `b` as a reference to `a`, so any changes to `a` also effect `b`

Comment: what do you mean by reference exactly? In what ways can i use references?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`b = a` is an assignment by reference: it makes the variable `b` point at the same list that variable `a` is pointing to. So when you update the contents of that list on the next line, with `a[:] = ...` then both `a` and `b` are pointing to the updated list.

If the next line had been `a = [x**2 for x in a]` (instead of `a[:] = ...`) that would have created a new list `[1,9,25]` and assigned the variable `a` to point at it, leaving `b` still pointing at the original list.

Comment: So what is the use of such references?

Comment: @Ankit it saves memory, plus a number of other things that I'm sure a google search would let you know about.

Comment: Pass-by reference is very quick and memory-efficient: you only change one memory location instead of many. But there are side-effects that you need to be aware of - hence the examples you're looking at.

Comment: @Ankit for more info go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/a/986145/98806

Comment: @Ankit don't overthink this- you're a beginner, so for now, just stick to the rule of NOT doing this: `a = b`.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `b = a`, you simply creating a reference to the variable `a` and this reference is named `b`. A reference is just another name for the same object. You are not creating a copy of the variable `a`. Therefore, if you modify `b`, it modifies `a` as well and vice versa.

However, if you do `b = a[:]`, you are creating a shallow copy of the variable `a` and assigning it to a new variable called `b`. Since `b` is a copy, modifying either one of them, won't change the other.

That is precisely why you get two different answers when printing `b` at the end.